# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request, "Не найден указанный модуль"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm following on the MVC tutorial of Rick Anderson , [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) , page 4 , after added the Model and Database . However , when I try to go to the URL of :

```
http://localhost:2815/Movies/Index
```

I get this : [image: here]

And this :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Не найден указанный модуль

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Не найден указанный модуль

Source Error: 


Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
Line 21:         }
Line 22: 

Source File: c:\Users\X\Desktop\Projects\MVC5\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MoviesController.cs    Line: 20 

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Не найден указанный модуль]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5363103
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<UsingConnection>b__2d() +73
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +229
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +376
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +201
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +87

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +271
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +33

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +193
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) +32
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +43
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +611
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   MvcMovie.Controllers.MoviesController.Index() in c:\Users\X\Desktop\Projects\MVC5\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:20
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

But this is weird since the **MoviesController.cs** , is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

        // GET: /Movies/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }

       // ... more code 

}
```

And the method public **ActionResult Index()** has an implementation of the HTML in the View library :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

So , what's the reason for the exception ?

Comment: the error is *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.*

Comment: In the `Index` method can you add something like `var test = db.Movies.ToList();` and tell us when this is execute does `test` contains the actual data from `Movies` table or you get the same exception?

Answer (score 1):

I obviously can't read the exception message, however it looks like your view expects a model of type `List<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>`. More than likely your database context is not returning that type. It appears to be returning a list of Entity Framework data objects.

You'd need to convert your entity type to your model type. You can either use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to do this automatically after some minimal setup, or you can do it manually:

```
var movies = new List<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>();
foreach (var movie in db.Movies)
{
    movies.Add(new MvcMovie.Models.Movie {
        Title = movie.Title,
        Year = movie.Year,
        Format = movie.Format
        //etc...
    });
}

return View(movies);
```

Not sure if this is your actual problem but it might be worth checking based on a quick look at your code.