# MVC Movie Project - Multiple Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**strong text**I'm attempting to run the MVC Movie Project, located here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

When I attempt to run it, I'm given an error in the MoviesController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}
```

Which states: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

I researched this and discovered some people has success by changing the connectionString "MovieDBContext" value from this:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

to this:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

That seems to let it run further, but then it errors out again at the same place in MoviesController.cs ...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}
```

with a new error:
**"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."**

I did a search looking for suggestions to what this was, including these posts:
[System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatible Exception in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355803/system-data-entity-core-providerincompatible-exception-in-mvc-5)
[An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request, "Не найден указанный модуль"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437334/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-during-the-execution-of-the-current-web-request)

It would suggest that my "Movies.mdf" file is missing, but when I check the App_Data folder its there.  One person suggested recreating LocalDB, I'm not sure what that is or how I'd do that.  As you can tell I'm very new to .NET.  Any suggestions are very much appreciated.  Thank you for reading.

Comment: Click on your Model.edmx in solution explorer , Model.edmx diagram window will open right click any where in that window and click properties there you will see a property connectionString copy that connection string and paste it in web.config and see if it works.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I don't see that file.  Here's a link that shows all the files I have in Solution Explorer. [link](http://www.ironclads.com/temp/solutionexplorer.gif)

Comment: @MairajAhmad Also, this connection is already added in the web.config file: '    <add name="MovieDBContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"'

Comment: You are right that this is already there but from properties window  you can copy the exact connection string and replace with the existing.